# Atomic file write operations (cross platform)

Tags: java, python, file, file-io

How do I build up an atomic file write operation? The file is to be written by a Java service and read by python scripts.
For the record, reads are far greater than writes. But the write happens in batches and tend to be long. The file size amounts to mega bytes.

*Right now my approach is:*

- Write file contents to a temp file in
  same directory
- Delete old file
- Rename temp file to old filename.

Is this the right approach? How can avoid conditions where the old file is deleted but the new filename is yet to be renamed?

Do these programming languages (*python and java*) offer constructs to lock and avoid this situation?

Comment: Side note: it looks like Java NIO.2 has better support for this (at least at the API level): http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html#moveTo%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812115/how-to-safely-write-to-a-file

Comment: @Pascal . Its in Java 7. Long way to go... :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK no.

And the reason is that for such an atomic operation to be possible, there has to be OS support in the form of a transactional file system.  And none of the mainstream operating system offer a transactional file system.

**EDIT** - I'm wrong for POSIX-compliant systems at least.  The POSIX `rename` syscall performs an atomic replace if a file with the target name already exists ... as pointed out by @janneb.  That should be sufficient to do the OP's operation atomically.

However, the fact remains that the Java `File.renameTo()` method is explicitly *not* guaranteed to be atomic, so it does not provide a cross-platform solution to the OP's problem.

**EDIT 2** - With Java 7 you can use `java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)` with copyOptions and `ATOMIC_MOVE`.  If this is not supported (by the OS / file system) you should get an exception.

Comment: +1:  Ahhh, those pesky OS differences preventing a "cross platform" solution.

Comment: A real answer is that file locks should be used instead.

Comment: "And none of the mainstream operating system offer a transactional file system." What?? NTFS has had transaction support for a long time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx

Comment: @unixman83 you could lock the new file while you're writing data into it, but then how do you lock a directory to do the atomic swap? :)

Comment: @Ark-kun - I did not know that.  However, it doesn't actually help because that functionality is not available on most file systems, and it is not exposed via the standard Java APIs.

Answer (score 7):

At least on POSIX platforms, leave out step 3 (delete old file). In POSIX, rename within a filesystem is guaranteed to be atomic, and renaming on top of an existing file replaces it atomically.

Answer (score 3):

It's a classic producer/consumer problem. You should be able to solve this by using file renaming, which is atomic on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, Solaris, Unix this is easy. Just use `rename`() from your program or `mv`. The files need to be on the same filesystem.

On Windows, this is possible if you can control both programs. `LockFileEx`. For reads, open a `shared lock` on the lockfile. For writes, open an `exclusive lock` on the lockfile. Locking is weird in Windows, so I recommend using a separate *lock file* for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Java FileLock API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)

Comment: Yea ... but this won't allow you to do an atomic file replace.

Comment: You are not fully right.
With this api you can create ".lock" file and use it as semaphore.
Usecase: if file is locked - python wait until it get unlocked, then start read (and lock file), after reading unlock file. When service need write data - check, if file is locked, wait until it become unlocked, lock it, write data, unlock it.

Comment: Anyhow, this is effectively a link-only Answer, and the link does not explain how to solve the OP's question.  By today's standards it is a low quality answer.

Comment: Important part from the documentation: "Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified. "

Comment: @St.Shadow, a lock prevents _another copy of your program that's running correctly_ from changing things at the same time, but it doesn't mean an OS crash, or a JVM error, or so forth won't leave your file partially-written or otherwise corrupt (which a proper atomic create-and-rename workflow will).

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use an extra file to act as a lock, but I'm not sure if that will work out ok. (It would force you to create lock-checking and retry logic at both sides, java and python)

Another solution might be to not create files at all, maybe you could make your java process listen on a port and serve data from there rather than from a file?

Answer (score 1):

Have the python scripts request permission from the service.  While the service is writing it would place a lock on the file.  If the lock exists, the service would reject the python request.